# Datepicker with react-redux not working "expected instance of Date"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, momentjs

I'm creating a form using redux-form react-datepicker and moment but I'm getting an error with the date format.

Its shows multiple errors and an Invalid Input Field message in the datepicker

Here is my form utility:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Form, Label } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker'
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'
import moment from 'moment'

const DateInput = ({input, width, placeholder, meta: {touched, error}, ...rest}) => {
    return(
        <Form.Field error={touched && !!error} width={width}>
            <DatePicker 
                {...rest}
                placeholderText={placeholder}
                selected={input.value ? moment(input.value) : null}
                onChange={input.onChange}
            />
            {touched && error && <Label basic color="red">{error}</Label>}
        </Form.Field>
    )
}

export default DateInput
```

And the component import using redux-form Field

```
<Field
 name="date"
 type="text"
 component={DateInput}
 dateFormat="YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm"
 timeFormat="HH:mm"
 showTimeSelect
 placeholder="Date and time of event"
/>
```

I already used moment().format() to show the date on the datepicker field but then it shows up this error:

Invalid prop `selected` of type `Moment` supplied to `DatePicker`, expected instance of `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

In the propTypes defined, you need to change

```
selected: PropTypes.instanceOf(Date)
```

to

`selected: PropTypes.instanceOf(Moment)`